# How to install LineageOS in TWRP using `adb push`?

Tags: adb, twrp, lineageos, side-loading

### Question (TL;DR)

How can one (manually) sideload a LineageOS zip file that is pushed on the phone using TWRP?

### Context

while installing [this `lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip`](https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/lineageos/full/FP2/20210430/lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip), with the following command:

```
adb sideload lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip
```

I observed that the lineageOS hangs in the loading screen for several hours. So first I verified that the `zip` file is correctly downloaded, using the sha256, which it is. Next, I noticed that the cause might be that the zip is streamed directly from the host to phone. So I learned an alternative option might be to use:

```
adb push lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip /sdcard/
```

Followed by a command to sideload the zip from the phone.

### adb sideload method

For completeness, the direct `adb sideload lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip` was performed using the following steps:First, I wiped the system using `Wipe>Advanced Wipe> select: Dalvik, System, Cache, Data, and swiping right`, then  manually activated sideload mode by pressing (and swiping): `Advanced>ADB Sideload>Swipe to Start Sideload` which outputted:

> Updating partition details...
> ... done
> RescueParty
> Full SELinux support is present
> MTP Enabled
> ? Starting ADB sideload feature...

An observation is made here that the loading indicator keeps on loading without any progress. This might also be a reason the sideload does not yield a successful boot up of LineageOS.

Next, I tried I first tried the CLI approach:

```
adb sideload /sdcard/lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip
```

Which outputs:

> Installing zip file `/sideload/package.zip`
> Unmounting System
> Warning: no file_contexts
> Target: Fairphone/FP2/FP2:6.0.1/FP2-gms-18.04.01/FP2-gms-18.04.01:user/release-keys
> Patching system image unconditionally
> Script succeeded: result was [1.000000]
> Formatting Cache using make_ext4fs...
> Wiping Cache & Dalvik...
> Cleaned: /data/dalvik-cache...
> -- Dalvik Cache Directories Wipe Complete!

And I pressed `Reboot System`. This results in the (seemingly) endless booting of the LineageOS loading screen.

#### adb push method

Before I tried other builds for the FP2, I was mainly curious to learn how the sideloading would work using `adb push`. Hence, I tried:

```
adb push lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip /sdcard/
```

And started looking for ways to sideload that zip from the phone. The first thing I tried was, after starting the sideload mode manually and verifying that the TWRP was in sideload mode with command `adb devices`:

```
adb sideload /sdcard/lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip
```

Which returns:

> adb: failed to stat file /sdcard/lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip: No such file or directory

Next, I tried exploring the TWRP options manually. One of the options could possibly be: `Install>browse to /sdcard> and tap the: lineage-17.1-20210430-nightly-FP2-signed.zip`. However that yields a warning:

```
This operation may install incompatible software and render your device unusable
```

And I think installing might be something else than sideloading, hence I think this might brick the device/not be what I am looking for.

### Note

This is not about the `xy-problem` of making LineageOS boot on the Fairphone, it is about how to load LineageOS using TWRP from the phone instead of from the host.

Comment: Your comment resolved the xy-problem. From TWRP I first tried `adb reboot fastboot` and `fastboot format userdata` which yielded a set of errors starting with: `Couldn't parse erase-block-size '0x'.`. Then rebooted into TWRP and did a format of: `Dalvik, System, Cache, Data` then `adb sideload ..zip`, then pressed `back>Wipe>swiped format` and then rebooted, and then LineageOS actually booted correctly! I didnt (yet) derive if it was the format, or wiping of `data` (not userdata) in TWRP after sideloading LineageOS that resolved the error. The instructions don't mention wiping data afterwards.

Comment: Yes, for clarity/completeness, that is to be done *before* sideloading LineageOS, which I already did, which resulted in the error. Your suggestion was to do that *after* sideloading LineageOS, which I initially did not do, and after I did it, (along with `fastboot format userdata`), the issue was resolved. So I think it is valid to indicate that the recommendation to remove userdata *after* sideloading LineageOS is not included in the instructions you link to. Whereas, from my experience, and your comment, it seems important/essential.

Comment: order doesn't matter except you are installing zip from internal storage. because */sdcard* is bind mount of */data/media/0* (and therefore erased when userdata is formatted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the headline only:

**only block partition images can be flashed with** `adb push`

- extract zip file
- convert sparse file into partition image

  ```
  brotli --decompress --in system.new.dat.br --out system.new.dat
  python sdat2img.py system.transfer.list system.new.dat system.img
  ```
- flash partition images from adb in TWRP recovery

  ```
  adb push boot.img /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot
  adb push system.img /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system
  ```

---

**Don't forget to factory reset / format the whole user data**

- can be done from `adb shell`

  ```
  adb shell
  mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache
  mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata
  ```

---

For more alternative methods to manually install OTA flashable zip
[Is it possible to flash a custom ROM without a custom recovery image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207256/is-it-possible-to-flash-a-custom-rom-without-a-custom-recovery-image)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why the factory reset is required after pushing the image(s) onto the device? Or share a source that discusses this?