# how to install OTA updates on TWRP rooted stock image

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, custom-roms, ota-update, magisk

I have a `stock ROM Android 10` on which I installed `TWRP recovery` and `magisk root`

now my stock ROM after quite some time offered an `OTA update`
,
and it will not install ,obviously ,via `TWRP`.  my device is `type A only` ( unlike  `A / B type`) for which there is [this detailed guide](https://googleweblight.com/sp?u=https://www.thecustomdroid.com/install-ota-update-rooted-android-device-guide/&grqid=xQS-L7RT&hl=x-hacker) which I cannot use.

I then I read about this module
[`DM verify no encrypt`](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/universal-dm-verity-forceencrypt-disk-quota-disabler-11-2-2020.3817389/)

**Questions**  
-will flashing this module help resolve this issue &  I should be able to install OTA updates seamlessly through my current recovery  
-if the former isn't relevant what would be the approach for a `Type A` phone to install `OTA updates` *other than* just restore original `stock boot` and `recovery` and once again re install custom recovery and re-root, which is painstaking.  
-to install the above-mentioned module should I `decrypt` my phone which I think is encrypted I have a `fingerprint pattern` and `password lock`

additional observations  
I could manage to get hold of the update zip and changing permissions  permitted me to open the zip file.

I see two files that attract - in terms of of giving hope that I can tinker this update.zip so that it can install without a verification

**updater**
found here at this path  
`/storage/emulated/0/update.zip/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script` 
entire script is [uploaded here](https://pastebin.com/qv3pYwgd)

and *otacert* found here  
`/storage/emulated/0/update.zip/META-INF/com/android/otacert`
and it looks like   
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIID2zCCA etc  -----END CERTIFICATE-----`

**approaches**  
 is it possible to *tweak the Updater script* and tell it not to do verification so it can be installed via simple TWRP

the other approach - certificate file that particular certificate can it be changed so that the content matches with the current phone hash. I don't know how to generate one that matches the current  phone

**update #2**

modified the Updater script and after deleting relevant portions I get this error . this is after two modifications to skip through verification errors which I overcame  
[original Updater script](https://paste.c-net.org/YourselfRattle)  
[modified Updater script used](https://paste.c-net.org/GarlicRoller)  
[recovery log](https://paste.c-net.org/SocietyThursday)

error that I get

```
Verified system image...Verified vendor image...Verified vendor image...
Verified product image...
Patching system image after verification.
performing update
Verified product image...Patching system image after verification.blockimg version is 4
maximum stash entries 0
creating stash /cache/recovery/cc46ebfd04058569d0c6c1431c6af6c1328458e4
405680128 bytes free on /cache (29192192 needed)
/cache/recovery/last_command doesn't exist.
stashing 468 overlapping blocks to f93e6436fba55bbb8e1990df38044cff68a4bf8f
405680128 bytes free on /cache (1916928 needed)
 writing 468 blocks to /cache/recovery/cc46ebfd04058569d0c6c1431c6af6c1328458e4/f93e6436fba55bbb8e1990df38044cff68a4bf8f
patching 468 blocks to 467
Failed to write 409256 bytes of data: Operation not permitted
ERROR 10-08 01:39:43 external/bsdiff/bspatch.cc:324: Error writing to new file.: Operation not permitted
bspatch failed, result: 1
Failed to apply bsdiff patch.
Failed to apply image patch.
failed to execute command [imgdiff 0 9878 f93e6436fba55bbb8e1990df38044cff68a4bf8f 3c32c4f15abb00cab0e4103c3bf09ac67b7ceff8 2,218312,218779 468 2,218312,218780]
new data receiver is still available after executing all commands.
script aborted: E1001: Failed to update system image.
E1001: Failed to update system image.error: 1001
cause: 115
Patch application failed, retry update.
E:unknown command [retry_update]
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
I:Install took 16 second(s).
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/update.zip'
Updating partition details...`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to flash a custom ROM without a custom recovery image?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207256/is-it-possible-to-flash-a-custom-rom-without-a-custom-recovery-image)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a firmware without losing your data and restore the previous one in case it goes wrong?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219699/how-to-install-a-firmware-without-losing-your-data-and-restore-the-previous-one)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138174/discussion-on-question-by-user1874594-how-to-install-ota-updates-on-twrp-rooted).