# Is it possible to flash a custom ROM (say Lineage OS) with adb/fastboot?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot

i have TWRP recovery installed, but i am looking for a way to flash the zip (after extracting) directly with fastboot. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You would be needing this tool for image conversion. https://github.com/xpirt/sdat2img

Comment: @Firelord , what is the difference between sparse data and raw image (ext filesystem )?/what I mean is which one really is required by android to boot the system ?

Comment: That I don't know about. I had a device which I couldn't flash using recovery, and so, came across that tool. That's why I recommended it. Other folks might know the difference.

Comment: *"which one really is required"* depends on how to flash it. the partition itself is of course always ext4 file system. all other file formats exist only to safe disk space (excluding the empty gaps)

Comment: Note: fastboot has size limit. depending on ROM and fastboot version one must split *system.img* into *system.img_sparsechunk.0* files [manually](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219173) or via [argument](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/163922)

Comment: @alecxs, I think converting the raw img file to sparse image handless the splitting part. I use img2simg for that purpose and after converting , I see the flashing takes place in multiple chunks. https://coral.googlesource.com/img2simg/